# c++ template metaprogramming: how to create and iterate over list of types that are "typedefs" in template class.

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, factory-pattern, alexa-internet

My code is a factory that creates objects based on types from template parameters. I want to extend this to a "list of" types.

This is what I have:  **`Algo1`** defines a type **`indata`. `FASSubscriberFactory::Create()`** returns a pointer to **`FASSubscriber<Algo1::indata,..>`** . See here:

```
struct Algo1  
{
    typedef DataType1 indata;
}

template <class T, class FEED = T::indata, class PROC = typename ProcessorFactory<T>::ptype>
struct FASSubscriberFactory
{
    typedef FASSubscriber<typename PROC , typename FEED > fftype;

    static fftype * Create()
    {
        return new fftype(FASConfig::Data2Feed<FEED>::name, ProcessorFactory<T>::Create());
    }
}

void main() 
{
    auto myFASSubscriber4Algo1 FASSubscriberFactory<Algo1>::Create();
}
```

This is what I want:  **`Algo1`** defines a list of typedefs  **`indata`. `FASSubscriberFactory::CreateList()`** returns a pointer to a list of **`FASSubscriber<Algo1::indata,..>`** *foreach* type in **`Algo1:indata`**. See //comments in pseudocode below.

```
struct Algo1 
{
    //Want to define a list of types
    typedef std::list<types> indata = { DataType1, DateType2 }
}

template <class T, class FEEDs = T::indata, class PROC = typename ProcessorFactory<T>::ptype>
struct FASSubscriberFactory
{
    //want to create a list FASSubscribers from list of types T::indata
    typedef list<FASSubscriber<PROC, FEEDs::type> listoffftypes 
    static lisoftypes * CreateList()
    {
        listoffftypes mylot();

        //for each type in FEEDs - want to lopp around list of types
        foreach(feedtype in FEEDs )
        {
            mylot.push(Create<feedtype>());
        }
        return mylot; 
    }

    template <class FEED>
    static fftype * Create()
    {
        typedef FASSubscriber<typename PROC , typename FEED > fftype;

        return new fftype(FASConfig::Data2Feed<FEED>::name, ProcessorFactory<T>::Create());
    }
}

void main() 
{
    auto myListOfFASSubscriber4Algo1 FASSubscriberFactory<Algo1>::Create();
}
```

All I really want is a way to define and iterate over a "typelist" which is defined in the template argument class.  Took a look at A. Alexa's TYPELISTS, but I didnt see any loops.

thanks
j

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling variadic templates and `std::tuple` from C++11 is what you want, although I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're asking.

```
// returns a tuple of pointers created by a Create for each type in the parameter pack
template<typename... TS>
static std::tuple<TS*...> CreateList() {
    return { Create<TS>()... };
}
```

Please don't describe template metapogramming in terms of normal C++ code; it is confusing.

---

For instance if you called it like this:

```
FASSubscriberFactory</* stuff */>::CreateList<int, float, foo, bar>()
```

It would essentially be doing this:

```
static std::tuple<int*, float*, foo*, bar*> CreateList() {
    return { Create<int>(), Create<float>(), Create<foo>(), Create<bar>() };
}
```

Comment: what is a better way to describe it? in your example TS is a collection of types? So does the pre-processor create multiple types of CreateList<>, once for each type in TS?

Comment: ok, so the ...operator causes a new block of code for each type? hmmm... interesting. but can they share static variables? need to read up on variadic templates. ty

Comment: @jaybny I updated with how it gets "expanded". Yeah, go read up on variadic templates, try them out, and let me know if you have any questions then.

Comment: will do. but currently in VS2010, so was hoping for a boost::library. maybe this will push me to vs2012.

Comment: @jaybny You might want to check out Boost.MPL which works in C++03