# How to instantiate a list of types for compile-time/static polymorphism

Tags: c++, embedded, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm implementing a compile time dispatcher which makes use of static polymorphism and metaprogramming.

I have a list of types which I would like to instantiate into a runtime `std::array`.

```
struct Test
{
     typedef std::integral_constant<int,0> nop;
     typedef std::integral_constant<int,1> A;
     typedef std::integral_constant<int,2> B;
     typedef std::integral_constant<int,3> C;

     using list = mp_list<A, B, C>; // mp_list expands to: template<A, B, C> struct {};

     struct Things{
         int (Test::*process)(int foo, float bar);
         const std::string key;
         int something;
         float other;
     };

     typedef std::array<Things, mp_size<list>::value> Thing_list;
     Thing_list thing_list;

     template<typename T=nop> int process(int foo, float bar);

     // stuff...

     Test();
}
```

In the above code, `mp_list` is simply a variadic template which 'expands' to `struct<A, B, C> mp_list`. And likewise, `mp_size` gives an mp implementation of the `sizeof`.

As can be inferred, the `Thing_list` is an array with a compile-time known size.

I can then specialize a template function like so:

```
template<> int process<Test::B>(int foo, float bar){ /* do stuff */ };
```

to achieve compile-time polymorphism.

The above code works well, except that to initialize it, I am stuck at doing this in the constructor:

```
Test::Test() thing_list({{{&Test::process<A>, "A"}, // this all should be achieved through meta-programming
                          {&Test::process<B>, "B"},
                          {&Test::process<C>, "C"}}}} )
{
   // stuff
}
```

There are two things I'm unable to get right:

1. I would like to have a MP based initialization of the list. As I update the `list` definition in the declaration, I would like my initialization to automatically reflect that list type.
2. I would also like to avoid having to duplicate the name of the type as a string literal. I have tried to use something like `integral_constant` but the use of `const char*` as a template parameter seems to be forbidden. I am left to having to duplicate declaration (triplicate, really).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13856112/4514378) answer is almost the solution: it takes a list of types and instantiates them like so:

```
static std::tuple<int*, float*, foo*, bar*> CreateList() {
return { Create<int>(), Create<float>(), Create<foo>(), Create<bar>() };
}
```

However, I'm stuck on converting from `std::tuple` to `std::array`.

The main question is #1. Bonus for #2 without using `#define` based trickery.

If anyone cares: this code is destined for embedded software. There are dozens of different types, and importantly, each type (e.g. `A`, `B`, `C`) will have an identically structured configuration to be loaded from memory (e.g. under a configuration key for `"A"`) - hence the reason of wanting to have access to the string name of the type at runtime.

Comment: You can never get the name of a variable/type as a string unless you explicitly specify it somewhere.

Comment: For an approach to the general problem posed, I would do something like `auto thing_list = make_thing_list<list>();`.

Comment: `CreateList` as shown in the link I provided does `make_thing_list<list>()`, however, it creates a `std::tuple`. For the life of me, I can't make a tuple into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing the `typedef`s for A, B and C to struct so you can define the string inside them.

```
struct A {
    static constexpr int value = 1;
    static constexpr char name[] = "A";
};

// Same for B and C

using list = mp_list<A, B, C>;
```

Then you can create a `make_thing_list`

```
template <typename... T>
static std::array<Things, sizeof...(T)> make_thing_list(mp_list<T...>) {
    return {{{&Test::process<T>, T::name}...}};
}

auto thing_list = make_thing_list(list{});
```

Complete example

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename... T>
struct mp_list {};

struct Test
{
    struct nop {
        static constexpr int value = 0;
        static constexpr char name[] = "nop";
    };
    struct A {
        static constexpr int value = 1;
        static constexpr char name[] = "A";
    };
    struct B {
        static constexpr int value = 2;
        static constexpr char name[] = "B";
    };
    struct C {
        static constexpr int value = 3;
        static constexpr char name[] = "C";
    };

     using list = mp_list<A, B, C>; // mp_list expands to: template<A, B, C> struct {};

     struct Things{
         int (Test::*process)(int foo, float bar);
         const std::string key;
         int something;
         float other;
     };

    template <typename... T>
    static std::array<Things, sizeof...(T)> make_thing_list(mp_list<T...>) {
        return {{{&Test::process<T>, T::name}...}};
    }

    using Thing_list = decltype(make_thing_list(list{}));

    Thing_list thing_list = make_thing_list(list{});

     template<typename T=nop> int process(int foo, float bar) {
         return T::value;
     }

     // stuff...

     Test() {}
};

int main() {
    Test t;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t.thing_list), std::array<Test::Things, 3>>);

    for (auto& thing : t.thing_list) {
        std::cout << thing.key << (t.*thing.process)(1, 1.0) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I really like the inline initialization of `thing_list` without needing to mess with the constructor.

Comment: This may be a different question, but `g++  8.3.0` allows me to compile this, but the linker says `undefined reference to 'Test::A::name'`.

If I used `static consexpr char *name = "A";` instead, it links fine, but I get a compiler warning (`ISO C++ forbids converting string constant to char*`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried editing your post (not sure if SO was down or not): changing to `static constexpr char const * const name = "A";` solves this issue.

Comment: @MB. The rules for this has changed subtly in c++11, 14 and 17. I believe this code should compile ok in c++17 or later. The reason being that since then `constexpr` also implies `inline` for a static member. When a question doesn't specify a version I usually assume c++17 is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want but...

Given that you can use at least C++17 (for `auto` template parameters), you can define outside your class some variables as

```
static constexpr char nops[] = "NOP";
static constexpr char A[] = "A";
static constexpr char B[] = "B";
static constexpr char C[] = "C";
```

Then a simple wrapper that accept `nops`, `A`, `B`, etc. as template parameters

```
template <auto val>
struct wrap
 { };
```

Then a `using` that, given a variadic list of template value parameters, create a `mp_list` of `wrap` types

```
template <auto ... vals>
using wrapper = mp_list<wrap<vals>...>;
```

At this point... I suppose that, inside `Test`, you can define `nop` and `list` as follows

```
using nop = wrap<nops>;

using list = wrapper<A, B, C>;
```

Using delegating constructor, meta-programming way to initialize your `thing_list` could be the following

```
template <auto ... vals>
Test (mp_list<wrap<vals>...>) 
   : thing_list{{{&Test::process<wrap<vals>>, vals}...}}
 { }

Test () : Test{list{}}
 { }
```

If you modify the `list` adding a `D` parameter (where `D` is the `"D"` literal)

```
using list = wrapper<A, B, C, D>;
```

automagically the you get an additional `{&Test::process<wrap<D>>, D}` element in your `thing_list`.

The following is a full compiling C++17 example

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
struct mp_list
 { };

template <typename>
struct mp_size;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct mp_size<mp_list<Ts...>>
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>
 { };

static constexpr char nops[] = "NOP";
static constexpr char A[] = "A";
static constexpr char B[] = "B";
static constexpr char C[] = "C";

template <auto val>
struct wrap
 { };

template <auto ... vals>
using wrapper = mp_list<wrap<vals>...>;


struct Test
 {
   using nop = wrap<nops>;

   using list = wrapper<A, B, C>;

   struct Things
    {
      int (Test::*process)(int foo, float bar);
      const std::string key;
      //   int something;
      //   float other;
    };

   using Thing_list = std::array<Things, mp_size<list>::value>;

   Thing_list thing_list;

   template<typename T=nop> int process(int foo, float bar)
    { return 0; }

   template <auto ... vals>
   Test (mp_list<wrap<vals>...>) 
      : thing_list{{{&Test::process<wrap<vals>>, vals}...}}
    { }

   Test () : Test{list{}}
    { }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Test  t;
 }
```